# pipe operator between two blocks

Tags: bash

I've found an interesting bash script that with some modifications would likely solve my use case. But I'm unsure if I understand how it works, in particular the pipe between the blocks.

How do these two blocks work together, and what is the behaviour of the pipe that separates them?

```
function isTomcatUp {

    # Use FIFO pipeline to check catalina.out for server startup notification rather than
    # ping with an HTTP request. This was recommended by ForgeRock (Zoltan).

    FIFO=/tmp/notifytomcatfifo
    mkfifo "${FIFO}" || exit 1
    {
        # run tail in the background so that the shell can
        # kill tail when notified that grep has exited
        tail -f $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out &
        # remember tail's PID
        TAILPID=$!
        # wait for notification that grep has exited
        read foo <${FIFO}
        # grep has exited, time to go
        kill "${TAILPID}"
    } | {
        grep -m 1 "INFO: Server startup"
        # notify the first pipeline stage that grep is done
        echo >${FIFO}
    }
    # clean up
    rm "${FIFO}"
}
```

Code Source: https://www.manthanhd.com/2016/01/15/waiting-for-tomcat-to-start-up-in-a-script/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{ …; }` operations [groups the commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) such that the I/O redirections apply to all the commands within it.  The `{` must be separate as if it were a command name; the `}` must be preceded by either a semicolon or a newline and be separate too.  The commands are not executed in a sub-shell, unlike `( … )` which also has some syntactic differences.

In your script, you have two such groupings connected by a pipe.  Because of the pipe, each group *is* in a sub-shell, but it is not in a sub-shell because of the braces.

The first group runs `tail -f` on a file in background, and then waits for a FIFO to be closed so it can kill the `tail -f`.  The second part looks for the first occurrence of some specific information and when it finds it, stops reading and writes to the FIFO to free everything up.

As with any pipeline, the exit status is the status of the last group — which is likely to be 0 because the `echo` succeeds.

Comment: So if grep fails to find a match, exiting unsuccessfully, does that mean the FIFO won't be written to (and thus will remain open)? Is that something to do with the 'unit' execution of blocks?

Comment: No.  The exit status of `grep` is lost and the attempted write to the FIFO happens regardless. The exit status of that part of the pipeline will be the exit status from the `echo` which will be zero if it succeeds and non-zero otherwise.  Note that the code reading from the FIFO will be hung until a process opens it for writing, and vice versa.

Comment: I'm getting it now, thank you for your detailed responses :)

Answer (score 3):

`bash` has a whole set of *compound* commands, which work much like simple commands. Most relevant here is that each compound command has its own standard input and standard output.

`{ ... }` is one such compound command. Each command inside the group inherits its standard input and output from the group, so the effect is that the standard output of a group is the concatenation of its children's standard output. Likewise, each command inside reads in turn from the group's standard input. In your example, nothing interesting happens, because `grep` consumes all of the standard input and no other command tries to read from it. But consider this example:

```
$ cat tmp.txt
foo
bar
$ { read a; read b; echo "$b then $a"; } < tmp.txt
bar then foo
```

The first `read` gets a single line from standard input, and the second `read` gets the second. Importantly, the first `read` consumes a line of input before the second `read` could see it. Contrast this with

```
$ read a < tmp.txt
$ read b < tmp.txt
```

where `a` and `b` will both contain `foo`, because each `read` command opens `tmp.txt` anew and both will read the first line.